# Return Entity Framework objects as JSON with NancyFx

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, nancy

I'm building a small API (for read operations - GET) using NancyFX and C# with .NET 4.0

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 in order to access a SQL Server 2008R2 database.

I have the following route exposed with Nancy (this is just for testing purposes):

```
public ExampleNancyModule() 
{
    Get["/v1/address_types"] = parameters =>
    {
        var address_types = context.address_type.First();
        return Response.AsJson(address_types);
    };
}
```

I'm able to access the route with Postman, however I'm receiving an empty response body. How can I return the object and/or a list of objects with Nancy?

I guess there's more configuration that needs to be done first. I'm new with Nancy, I just started using it this morning. It seems promising!

Thanks for the support.

Comment: is there actually anything in `address_types` ?

Comment: Yes, the address_types var is not null, it contains the first row of the address_type table.

Comment: I did not check what `Response.AsJson` does but i usually get json response from nancy just with return statement. Try removing `Response.AsJson` and send `Content-Type:application/json` as header.

Comment: Thanks, I've found a solution I'll add it in a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this case:

I've changed the default Json Serializer that comes with Nancy with NewtonSoft.Json

The code in ExampleNancyModule remains the same, however I've added a Boostrap file to overwrite the default behaviour of Nancy. My Bootstrap.cs file looks like this:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Bootstrap : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
        {
            base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

            container.Register<JsonSerializer, CustomJsonSerializer>();
        }
    }

    public class CustomJsonSerializer : JsonSerializer
    {
        public CustomJsonSerializer()
        {
            this.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            this.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        }
    }
}
```

With this I can get a JSON response that respects the attributes and the JSON configuration of my Entity Framework Models. Hope this helps someone else.